# Search a table using a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which searches a table for a variable set by the user it works fine but the search only finds the first letter of the string input.

I'm using ->

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    @search_string varchar  
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF (@search_string IS NOT NULL) OR (LEN(@search_string) > 0)
        SELECT [archive_id]      
               [archive_id],
               [display_name]
        FROM [test1].[dbo].[ARCHIVE_id]
        WHERE [display_name] like @search_string+'%';
```

What I am trying to figure out is how I can search for a whole word in the display_name column.

Any help would be appreciated.

Mark

Comment: like '%' + @search_string+'%'

Comment: I tried that but it does not find anything.

Comment: You need to specify size of @search_string: `@search_string varchar(80) `. Default size is one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to declare the size of the variable

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[test]
    @search_string varchar(50)
```

This should work

Comment: The problem i get is say i search for 'nex' if finds all sorts of results like nm_mpeg rather than just results containing the word nex

Comment: Use Wild Card in the search clause properly.
it should be '%' + @variable + '%'

Comment: I get no results if i remove the wild cards

Comment: *Update the wildcard as above

Comment: Who downvoted this? This is the correct answer. If you do not specify the size be default it takes only one character here

Comment: Works fine I realized what I was doing wrong. As you originally said i did not verify the size once i resized it to 255 and ran with the '%'+@search+'%' it works fine. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

See [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

```
%  Any string of zero or more characters.
_   Any single character.
[ ]  Any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set ([abcdef]).
[^]   Any single character not within the specified range ([^a-f]) or set ([^abcdef]).
```